# Keep footer at the bottom when using absolute positioned main elements

Tags: html, css, footer

**Scenario**

I am using a page layout with three main elements.

x1 **central column**

```
position:relative;
padding-right:300px;
```

x2 **sidebar pieces** on the right side

**1-sidebartop**

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
height:250px;
width:300px;
```

**2-sidebarbottom**

```
position:absolute;
top:250px;
right:0;
width:300px;
```

**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
<div class="sidebartop"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="sidebarbottom"></div>
```

**Why am I doing it this way?**

Because I would like the sidebar to be fixed-width and let the central column take the rest of the horizontal available space.

**But... why am I splitting the same sidebar in two pieces, instead of floating or inline-block aligning the two columns?**

Because I want the upper side of the sidebar to stay before the main content on mobile devices, for which I just do `position:relative;` to all elements, so they flow into the desired mobile structure.

**So what's the problem?**

The sidebar structure makes it quite complex to keep the footer at the bottom. Right now I am using a javascript approach to reposition the footer on the fly. I am thinking about a clever way to achieve this with pure css.

You can see a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/44wmqz00/3/).

Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: Please provide a simplified JSBin or fiddle. I don't see a `div.sidebarbottom`

Comment: Position fixed and higher z-index ?

Comment: @JohannesJander Sorry. I should have done it before. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/44wmqz00/

Comment: Just set `position: fixed` on `.footer`? Or do I understand something wrong? BTW: you have a typo in the Fiddle CSS where you set `position: asoblute`

Comment: Updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/44wmqz00/3/). When I use fixed, the footer will always stay visible. What I am looking for indeed, is to keep the footer at the end of the document. Thanks for your time. Appreciating it.

Comment: _“The sidebar structure makes it quite complex to keep the footer at the bottom”_ – it is less the structure in itself, and more the absolute positioning. Building a whole page layout based on that is seldom a good idea. // What _content_ do your upper and lower halves of the sidebar contain? If one of them contains “not much” (not much data, not very relevant data), then it might be more prudent to have that content in two places in the HTML/DOM to begin with, and then show only one of those two instances based on whether it is displayed on mobile or not.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you sir. I actually learned from it. I updated the structure and used the solution suggested by Daniel because it really fits the situation (I use an advertisement code and cannot duplicate it in the HTML). All the best to all you out there. Stay cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and almost certainly should) do this without absolute positioning.

Here's one float-based method that preserves your document order and doesn't depend on positioning or fixed heights for any element:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topside,
.bottomside {
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background-color: #FFC;
}
.main {
  width: calc(100vw - 250px); /* <-- This is the interesting bit */
  float: left;
  background-color: #FCF
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #CFF
}
```

```html
<div class="topside">
  Sidebar Piece 1 [Stays before main on narrow screens]
</div>
<div class="main">
  MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS
  MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS MAIN CONTENTS

</div>
<div class="bottomside">
  Sidebar Piece 2
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Keep footer at bottom
</div>
</div>
```

(You could similarly use `calc` and `vh` to make your sidebar height match that of the main content area, but I believe this would require setting fixed heights on at least the footer and one half of the sidebar, as well as the header if any.)

Another possibility which I haven't worked out in detail yet: you could probably achieve the same effect by changing the document order to put both halves of your sidebar together (which would make your desktop layout much simpler to manage) and use `flex-direction` in your mobile layout to change the apparent order of the main and sidebartop blocks.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, for this Great answer. All the best.

Answer (score -2):

I think you Need like this.can you Please Check bellow Code...

Answer.`enter code here`

```css
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#header {
 background:#ededed;
 padding:10px;
}
#content {
 padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
 background:#ffab62;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="header">
  </div><!-- #header -->
  
  <div id="content">
  </div><!-- #content -->
  
  <div id="footer">
  </div><!-- #footer -->
  
 </div><!-- #wrapper -->
```